# React custom slider - showing bubble value on slider

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm in the process of creating a dynamic slider (hopefully!)
Here's what I have so far - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-framework-ld6ht?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Here's my slider component:

```
const RangeSlider = ({ classes, label, onChange, value, ...sliderProps }) => {
    const newValue = ((value - sliderProps.min) * 100) / (sliderProps.max - sliderProps.min);
    const newPosition = 10 - newValue * 0.2;

    return (
        <div className={styles.slider}>
            <p>{label}</p>
            <p>{sliderProps.min}</p>
            <div className={styles.rangeWrap}>
                <div className={styles.rangeValue} id={"rangeV"}>
                    <span style={{ left: `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))` }}>{value}</span>
                </div>
                <input
                    {...sliderProps}
                    type={"range"}
                    value={value}
                    className={`slider ${classes}`}
                    id={"myRange"}
                    onChange={onChange}
                />
            </div>
            <p>{sliderProps.max}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

This component above is being used as below in its parent's component:

```
const [sliderProps, setSliderProps] = useState({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 20,
    label: "This is a reusable slider",
});
const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(0);

const handleSliderChange = e => {
    setSliderValue(e.target.value);
};

....
.....
.....

<RangeSlider
   {...sliderProps}
   classes={styles.slider}
   onChange={handleSliderChange}
   value={sliderValue}
/>
```

I can't seem to get the calculation right for the bubble value. As you can see in the sandbox the bubble on top of the slider is moving in the opposite direction. What I want is to have it in sync on top of the slider as it moves/slides. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I modified this line newPosition to be... `const newPosition = 10 + newValue * 4.8;`. But the problem is you'll need the value `4.8` to be a scale of how long the bar is I'd think... But within the context of that sample... those values work.

Comment: Tried playing around with that line - It works okay but goes all weird when going down to smaller screen sizes..

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant... you'll probably need some additional js to determine the screen (or bar) width, and adjust that value as the screen resizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've stated in my comment, you'll need to detect the screen width to adjust the ratio value. Something like [this working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-firefly-yvxkk).

```
const size = useWindowSize();
const ratio = size.width / 100 - 0.35;
const newPosition = 10 + newValue * ratio;
```

I've just grabbed a `useWindowSize` hook from [here](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/), but you're welcome to use whatever other methods you deem fit to detect the window width, but I'd recommend you use hooks as its the standard (at least for) now.

FWIW. I've also adjusted the range wrap to be `width:100%` as opposed to hard coded to 500px just so it resizes (a bit better too)

```
.rangeWrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Update, as per your additional comments:**

You can update ratio calc to cater for the slider living in only certain sections of the pages layout. In your update you had a 2 column layout, so I'll go with that.

```
// breakpoint at which the layout shifts
const isDesktop = size.width > 770;

// mobile has a 1 col layout
const cols = isDesktop ? 2 : 1

// this seems to need some slightly 
// different values at the different layouts to look decent
const pxShift = isDesktop ? 0.4 : 0.5;

// voila!
const ratio = size.width / cols / 100 - pxShift;
```

Just to be clear... you don't HAVE to use page width.. The main thing is you need to find the width of the container that the slider is in, somehow, then base your calculations off of that containers width. Page width just came to mind the quickest, but there might be better solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the working example! Maybe I'm going mad but I tried to incorporate your working example and I'm still getting the bubble moving away from the slider track. Sorry for the lack of design, but I'm trying my best to incorporate how this slider is being used (It's essentially in a div inside a 2-col grid) - https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-bird-2bxls

Comment: thats easy. your width is basically halved (as your content area is now smaller). `const ratio = size.width / 2 / 100 - 0.3;` 2 in this case because you've effectively split the page width in 2...

Comment: You'll need to adjust the ratio value based on your layout... so if you do a 4 col layout... and the slider spans 3 of the 4 columns, you'll need to adjust the ratio to be page-width * 3/4... etc 
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-firefly-yvxkk?file=/src/slider.js

Comment: I believe this will need to be adapted on multi screen sizes.. and multiple breakpoints. I'm viewing in on by big screen and the bubble is off doing its business again

Comment: Yeah, its not pretty when you start to use js to detect device width etc... As it doesn't always play so well with responsive design... What we tend to use are different breakpoints, then at certain intervals you can do the needed tweaks etc...

Comment: E.g what you need to do is, when the layout shifts to stacked, you need to change the cols value to 1. You can potentially check if the width is smaller than x, then if so... use  a different cols value etc... Some other design libs have built in utils for doing these types of things.

Comment: Right okay - so maybe this approach is not ideal then :/

Comment: I'll update the answer anyway so you can see. I think its ok... and to be honest... I don't know / think there is a pure css to do it... I've just never needed to build these utils myself, as I tend to stick to the tools the libs provide. (Lazy I guess :P)
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-firefly-yvxkk?file=/src/slider.js

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll play around with the numbers. Still seems a bit off on desktop for some reason.. Had to put 5 in the cols for desktop.. which is odd but mobile is pretty close

Comment: @drifterOcean19 Ok last one, then I'm done. https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-firefly-yvxkk

But I see what you meant, it was off by a little... my OCD was going to drive me nuts. But good luck with the rest of this. You'll have to take into account things like padding on the containers etc as well, they might all differ based on your actual project :)